# Cannot make Subiquity see zfs zvol block device, like I could with Ubiquity

Tags: system-installation, zfs, ubiquity

I am playing around with the newer server installer TUI (Subiquity).  With the desktop installer (Ubiquity), I am able to pre-install zfs and create a zvol, then launch ubiquity and have the zvol seen as a usable block device.
See my manual walkthrough (https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-install-Ubuntu-18.04-to-a-Whole-Disk-Native-ZFS-Root-Filesystem-using-Ubiquity-GUI-installer) and my ubiquity wrapper script (https://github.com/ghfields/rpooler).

I would like to accomplish something similar with Subiquity.  I tried:
1) CTRL+ALT+F2
2) sudo su
3) snap stop subiquity
4) apt install zfsutils
5) zpool create rpool /dev/sda
6) zfs create -V 20g rpool/ubuntutemp
7) snap start subiquity
8) CTRL+ALT+F1

But when I get to the disk selection, still only shows the /dev/sda device, not /dev/zd0 zvol device.  Is there another step I can do to make the the Subiquity disk chooser act like the Ubiquity disk chooser?

Comment: I would have also added the subiquity tag, but it doesn't exist and I don't have enough street cred here yet.

Answer (score 1):

Subiquity doesn't allow installation to virtual devices, including zvols. The only way I could think of to get around this was to install to another disk, as you would with a zvol, and rsync the contents over from the disk instead, making sure to do the EFI/MBR setup as needed. You could also make a separate partition on your target disk, rsync over after installing, remove the temporary partition and resize the ZFS partition. It's unfortunately cumbersome.

I've opened a bug for this issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1811037) in case you want to add yourself as being affected by it.